# Upgrade UbiSlate 7Cx to Android 4.2 or above

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, ubislate

I recently purchased UbiSlate 7Cx. It is running on Android 4.0.1 and has 512 MB RAM. Since it is very slow in running application and sometime it hangs, I want to upgrade to 4.2 or 4.3.

Is it possible? If it's, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A rooting procedure is provided at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2683754, but a Google search yields no custom ROMs for your device.

Sorry, but it's either you build your own ROM, or stay at 4.0.1.